# Apexcharts Monday label is not showing on a week chart

Tags: typescript, vue.js, apexcharts

[Monday is not showing on a week timeframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5IEb.png)

**Context (Details beneath the code)**

*I am using a chart from the apexchart library and used it on a vue framework.
The name of each day is showing and only the firstday of the week is not showing*

| Vue js script file |

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue, { PropType } from 'vue';
import { VueApexChartsComponent } from '../interface/vueapexchartcomponent';

type Chartfields = {
    name: string;
    data: [];
    type: string;
}

export default Vue.extend({
    name: 'chart',
    props: {
        chartseries: {
            type: Object as () => Chartfields[]
        },
        timeperiod: String as PropType<string>,
        loading: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            },
    },

    data: () => ({
        title: 'Issues',
        timeperiod: 'Week',
        intervals: ['Week', 'Month'],
        chartseries: {},
        
        chartOptions: {

            chart: {
                id: 'issuechart',
                type: 'area',
                toolbar: {
                    show: false
                },
                zoom: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            xaxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                labels: {
                    format: 'dddd'
                },
            },
            yaxis: {
                show: true
            },
            tooltip: {
                x: {
                    format: 'dddd'
                }
            } 
        }
    }),
    methods: {
        updateChart () {
            if (this.timeperiod == 'Month') {
                const chart = this.$refs.chart as VueApexChartsComponent;

                chart.updateOptions({
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Current',
                        data: [30, 40, 60, 30, 40, 40, 30, 30, 40, 60, 30, 40, 40, 30, 30, 40, 60, 30, 40, 40, 30, 30, 40, 60, 30, 40, 40, 30, 40, 60, 30],
                        type: 'column'
                    }, {
                        name: 'Average',
                        data: [35, 45, 55, 35, 45, 45, 35, 35, 45, 55, 35, 45, 45, 35, 35, 45, 55, 35, 45, 45, 35, 35, 45, 55, 35, 45, 45, 35, 45, 55, 35],
                        type: 'line'
                        // color:   #FFA500
                    }, {
                        name: 'Previous',
                        data: [25, 35, 45, 35, 45, 40, 28, 25, 35, 45, 35, 45, 40, 28, 25, 35, 45, 35, 45, 40, 28, 25, 35, 45, 35, 45, 40, 28, 25, 35, 45],
                        type: 'column',
                        color: '#C2CCC5'
                    }],
                    xaxis: {
                        type: 'datetime',
                        labels: {
                            format: 'dd'
                        },
                        categories: [
                            '2021-03-01T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-02T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-03T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-04T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-05T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-06T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-07T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-08T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-09T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-10T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-11T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-12T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-13T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-14T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-15T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-16T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-17T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-18T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-19T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-20T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-21T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-22T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-23T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-24T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-25T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-26T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-27T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-29T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-30T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-31T00:00:00.000Z']
                    },
                    
                });
            } else {
                const chart = this.$refs.chart as VueApexChartsComponent;

                chart.updateOptions({
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Current',
                        data: [30, 40, 60, 30, 40, 40, 30],
                        type: 'column'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Average',
                        data: [35, 45, 55, 35, 45, 45, 35],
                        type: 'line'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Previous',
                        data: [25, 35, 45, 35, 45, 40, 28],
                        color: '#C2CCC5',
                        type: 'column'
                    }],
                    xaxis: {
                        categories: [
                            '2021-03-01T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-02T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-03T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-04T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-05T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-06T00:00:00.000Z',
                            '2021-03-07T00:00:00.000Z'],
                        type: 'datetime',
                        labels: {
                            format: 'dddd'
                        }, 
                    },
                    yaxis: {
                        show: true
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        x: {
                            format: 'dddd'
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    },
    mounted () {
        this.updateChart();
    }
});

</script>
```

**Details**

*I am not a experienced developer and this is my second post on Stackoverflow*

*This is what I have tried;*

*- Simply ctrl and -/+. This means I tried zooming in and out because it might need some more width, but this didn't work*

*- I tried to use a time span of 31-02-2021 till 06-03-21 (normally 01-03-2021 til 07-03-21 ). This means that the first day of the data is on a sunday and the last day is on Saturday. The outcome of this was that is doesn't start at sunday and it shows monday but only when I hover on it, so it didn't work, becasue their was no label for monday. The chart showed the timespan of Monday till saturday whilst i used dates from sunday till saturday*

*- I have also changed the width of the xaxis label by implementing the following*

```
xaxis: {
   labels: {
       format: 'dddd',
       maxWidth: 200
   },
```

*-The most recent attempt was using a timespan of 14 days. The outcome of this was that the first monday is not showing whilst the rest of the labels are showing the name of each day. (yikes)*

*-can anyone try this and see if you have the same issue, because i can not find an explanation*

Comment: Rather than adding lorem ipsum placeholder text, could you add a bit more detail about what you've tried already in terms of debugging (e.g. only shows 13-day labels for 14 days, tried different label formats)? This helps others in answering your question. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is also a good reference guide.

Comment: @OscarSchafer thanks for the reaction. I changed the title and added some details.